# database - method of comparing 2 keyless tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, comparison

I'm trying to work out how to compare two keyless (ie no column is a primary key or unique) tables that are supposed to have the exact same data. Ie a straight migration of tablea from my_schema1 to my_schema2.

I was thinking a possible method would be:

```
IF 
    count from 
    ((select * from my_schema1.tablea
    union
    select * from my_schema2.tablea))
    =
    count from
    ((select * from my_schema1.tablea
    union all
    select * from my_schema2.tablea) / 2)
 THEN
     --both tables would be identical (in record counts and all column values the same)
 ELSE
     --this means that the 2 tables are different in some way
 END IF
```

Nice to have feature: I would prefer to make the solution as generic as possible by eliminating the need to specify columns.

Comment: As there is no PK presumably duplicate rows can exist. How do you want those treated?

Comment: as long as both tables have the same duplicate rows that is fine. However, I would like to identify the scenario where one table had some duplicate rows that the other table didn't.

Comment: Your current query will fail for this then. If a table has one column `C` and only 2 rows both with the same value the `union` will return 1 row but `union all` 4 rows.

Comment: @KevinBurton - Your answer there won't deal with duplicates as required.

Comment: @KevinBurton - No it doesn't. It just checks that both tables have the same number of dupes. Not necessarily the same ones. If one  table has values `1,1,2` and the other `1,2,2` for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) 
from 
(
 ( select * from my_schema1.tablea 
   minus 
   select * from my_schema2.tablea
 )
 union 
 ( select * from my_schema2.tablea 
   minus 
   select * from my_schema1.tablea
 )
)

if count(*) = 0 then 
 THEN
     --both tables are identical 
 ELSE
     -- the 2 tables are different in some way
 end if;
```

Comment: If table1 has a row duplicated several times, but it only appears in table2 once, this will appear as a match.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have duplicates, you could do this...

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2)) AS unioned,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1)                                            AS table1,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)                                            AS table2
```

All three figures should be the same if the two tables match.

The same approach can be used if there are duplicates, by adding count field...

```
WITH
  table1 AS (SELECT a, b, c, d, COUNT(*) AS duplicates FROM table1 GROUP BY a, b, c, d),
  table2 AS (SELECT a, b, c, d, COUNT(*) AS duplicates FROM table2 GROUP BY a, b, c, d)
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2)) AS unioned,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1)                                            AS table1,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)                                            AS table2
```

Comment: when running this I get ORA-00911

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a single column `C` below. You would need to expand this out to the complete column list (not tested on Oracle so might be some minor syntax issues but the general approach should work)

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C ORDER BY C) AS RN
FROM T              
), T2 AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C ORDER BY C) AS RN
FROM T       
), T3 AS
(
SELECT * FROM T1 
MINUS
SELECT * FROM T2
), T4 AS
(
SELECT * FROM T2 
MINUS
SELECT * FROM T1
)
SELECT * FROM T3
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM T4
```

Comment: If i wanted to expand to more than one column would i change these like so: PARTITION BY C, no2col, no3col ORDER BY C, no2col, no3col ? Is there a way to do it without specifying any column names?

Comment: @toop - Yes to the first part, Can't think of any way for the second part.

Comment: when running this I get ORA-00911. Not sure if you can do a * with row_number().

Comment: `*` where? In the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY`? If so no you can't. You need to list the columns. But as I said this is completely untested in Oracle and might need tweaking. The approach should work though.

Comment: @toop - That should work. Quite possibly my use of CTEs is incorrect for Oracle though. You'll need to figure out the correct syntax for Oracle.

Comment: @toop: You need to have the table prefixed to the asterisk in order to include other fields: `SELECT T.*, ROW_NUMBER() ...`